# python scrapy rules webscraping through google results

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to get scrapy (1.0) to go through all google results, and I have no problem scraping the first page of results, but I cannot get the scraper to go through the following number of pages (I think it's called traversing?).

I attempted with "rules":

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

...

rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pnnext"]')), callback='parse_item', follow=True))
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
NameError: name 'Rule' is not defined
```

I really need it to follow the "Next" pages and crawl the results, until there are no more pages.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should import Rule from scrapy.spiders, like so:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
```

Check the [Scrapy crawlspider example](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example) if you miss any other imports.

Comment: Thanks Mathias. That solves the error I got from Rule :-). However, when I run the script, it still only scrapes results from the first page.

Comment: Are you sure your Xpath is correct? If I check google.com the Xpath for the "Next" link would be '//a[@id="pnnext"]'. Does that work?

Comment: No, I'm not sure at all about the xpath or whether the 'rules' written above is correct for the intended purpose. :-/ I tried your suggestion, but it still only gets the first page of results. Thanks

Comment: Just tried calling https://www.google.com/search?q=test with Scrapy and had success using the Xpath '//div[@id="foot"]//td[@class="b"][2]'. Hope this works for you.